# jQuery Dialog cannot see Global Variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, variables, dialog, global

I'm loading HTML in dialog when button is clicked on

```
$("button").live('click', function() {
    var $div = $('<div title="Form"></div>');
    $div.load('test.html #formModal').dialog({
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    })
})
```

**The HTML of #formModal looks like**

```
  <form id="form">
    <input id="input1" type="button" />
    <input ...
  </form>
  <p id="formEdit"></p>
```

At this point HTML is successfully loaded in dialog

I also have the following, which when `#input1` inside dialog is clicked, it will insert text inside `#formEdit`.

```
var $form = $('#form'); // global variable
var $formedit = $('#formEdit'); // global variable
$form.find('#input1').live('click', function(){
 $formedit.text('test'); //if i do $('#formEdit') instead of $formedit then it works
})
```

`$formedit` is not working here. It's not being passed to the click handler. it works fine if HTML was initially in `body` and not loaded in dialog using `load()`. What is causing this.

Comment: @mu `$('#formEdit')` works but not `$formedit`. This tell me that $formedit is being passed in.

Comment: @mu `$formedit` works if my HTML initially existed in DOM. But since i'm loading content inside dialog, it no longer works. I have to do `$('#formEdit')` for it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since forModal is loaded dynamically formEdit is not avaialble with the regular page load.

Try this instead:

```
$("button").live('click', function() {
    var $div = $('<div title="Form"></div>');
    $div.load('test.html #formModal', function(){
      //#######ASSIGN THE #formEdit once the load is complete
      $formedit = $('#formEdit');
    }).dialog({
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    });

})
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. 'var' makes variable local to the context(function, document or window).

Comment: That worked. But now i have 2 references of the variables, inside load and outside. Removing either will break it again. Do we need to have the variables declared in both places. Does it make a difference if i have var infront of the variables

Comment: @Pinkie:You still have one variable. Only difference is you are reassigning a value to the variable $formEdit. Infact you can change the definition of the variable to var $formedit = null; from var $formedit = $('#formEdit');

Comment: I have been trying to resolve this problem for two days. It makes sense now. Thanks @Chandu.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
var $form = $('#form'); // global variable
var $formedit = $('#formEdit'); // global variable
$form.find('#input1').live('click',{formedit: $formedit} , function(e){

 e.data.formedit.text('test'); //if i do $('#formEdit') instead of $formedit then it works
})
```